# React-facebook-pixel Purchase track problem

Tags: reactjs, facebook-pixel, facebook-pixel-helper

I'm using Facebook pixel lib for react (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-pixel V.^1.0.4) on react V.^16.12.0 and trying to track the value of purchase which an user done, but its value is visible at Facebook Pixel Helper Addon, but at facebook dev page its always 0.